# Regex to check if based on one condition other condition is met

Tags: regex, kotlin

I am trying to check along with other requirements if to_date is present then it must have current_date ahead of it and if to_timestamp is present in string then enforce condition that current_date_hour must be present ahead of it in string.

```
var filterExpr = "to_date(column, format) = 'current_date-3' "
var pattern = "(?i)(to_date|to_timestamp)\\(.*\\)\\s*={1,2}\\s*'current_date(_hour)?(\\s*-\\s*\\d+)'".toRegex()
if (pattern.containsMatchIn(filterExpr!!)) {
    println("it's there")
} else {
    println("not found")
}
```

At present the above regex also works for mismatched cases.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: If `'to_date'` is present can it be preceded by `'current_date'`? If `'to_timestamp'` is present can it be preceded by `'current_date_hour'`? Can neither `'to_date'` and `'to_timestamp'` be present? Can both be present? Your wording (in part by omission) implies that the answer to all four questions is "yes".

Comment: @CarySwoveland I reworded it. current_date_hour and current_date should be present ahead of to_timestamp and to_date. But in case of preceded if needed, adding or conditions in lookahead with  current_date before to_date should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for the conditions:

```
(?=to_date.*current_date\\b|to_timestamp.*current_date_hour)
```

which asserts, without consuming input, that what follows matches *either* `to_date.*current_date\b` *or* `to_timestamp.*current_date_hour`.

A word boundary `\b` has been added to prevent `current_date` matching the first part of `current_date_hour`.

Adding this to your existing pattern yields:

```
var pattern = "(?i)(?=to_date.*current_date\\b|to_timestamp.*current_date_hour)(to_date|to_timestamp)\\(.*\\)\\s*={1,2}\\s*'current_date(_hour)?(\\s*-\\s*\\d+)'".toRegex()
```

Comment: One issue in this was since current_date is a prefix in current_date_hour. It still gives me found if I have `to_date` and `current_date_hour` . I added this `(?=to_date.*current_date[^_]|to_timestamp.*current_date_hour)` and it works

Comment: Just add `[^_]` after `to_date.*current_date`  since current_date is common prefix

Comment: @AkshayHazari use a word boundary `\b` after `current_date` to make it not match `current_date_hour` (the underscore character is considered to be a word character). See edited answer.

Comment: I'd suggest adding a comment to your code explaining what this regex is doing, and why, as it probably won't be obvious to anyone else reading the code.

Comment: @gidds explanation so added.

Comment: @Bohemian Actually, I meant that for OP, who's going to be writing the code based on all this :-) But extra explanation is always good!